# Appium does not start the test on Expo App on Android

Tags: android, adb, appium

My goal is to run end-to-end tests with Appium on an App built with Expo (turtle-cli).

I try to start a test session with Appium-Desktop with this parameters:

```
{
  "platformName": "android",
  "deviceName": "ENU7N15B0300...",
  "app": "path-to-apk",
  "automationName": "UiAutomator2"
}
```

The app launches on the smartphone, but I get a timeout error from Appium:

```
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Cannot start the 'com.example.testetoeapplauda' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'adb -P 5037 -s ENU7N15B03007818 shell am start -W -n com.example.testetoeapplauda/host.exp.exponent.MainActivity -S' timed out after 20000ms'. Try to increase the 20000ms adb execution timeout represented by 'adbExecTimeout' capability
```

The interesting part is the adb shell command. When I run this command manually, the app launches, but the command does not finish - it just hangs forever.

```
$ adb -P 5037 -s ENU7N15B03007818 shell am start -W -n com.example.testetoeapplauda/host.exp.exponent.MainActivity -S
Stopping: com.example.testetoeapplauda
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.example.testetoeapplauda/host.exp.exponent.MainActivity }
```

When I remove the parameter `-W` it is not blocking.

Do you have advice on how to start Appium tests on an Expo app **OR** do you have any idea how I can change Appium to don't use the `-W` flag?

Here is the apk, if you want to test it: [expo-app-test apk file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19KtkEqIM5XfhVeUgKAOk9W40e3dpVKiG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From appium 1.14.0 there is the option to skip the waiting:

```
appWaitForLaunch: false
```

This will allow avoiding -W option on the `adb` command.
For now you have to install the appium beta version, because it is not released, yet.

`npm install -g appium@beta`

Comment: Full guide of testing Expo app with appium: https://medium.com/@g.jjoe64/testing-expo-apps-with-appium-e2e-dc0705175ef2